# Ruby on Rails: Error with create post button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

This problem is trivial but it's been driving me insane.

When I click the create button, nothing happens. I know it is something with the button itself because when I try to edit posts, nothing changes as well.

I think there is a problem of redirecting perhaps? I must have accidentally deleted something since it worked fine a day ago.

Posts Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      #if user logged in, show this, else, redirect to login page
      if params[:search]
        @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 4)
      else
        @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)

      end
    end

    def new
      @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def find_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end


    def destroy
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.destroy

      redirect_to posts_path
    end

    def update
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to @post

      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end
    

    private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :looking_for, :category, :future_plans,[:photo])
    end

end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #resources
  resources :users, only: [:create, :new, :destroy]
  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :new, :destroy]
  resources :posts

  #posts routes
  root 'posts#index'
  get '/newpost' => 'posts#new'

  #User routes
  get '/signup' => 'users#new'

  #session routes
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

New post HTML

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "newpost.css" %>

<%=link_to "Return to menu", posts_path, class:'menubutton'%>

  <h2 id='header'>Create a new project!</h2>
  <div id = 'form'>
    <%= render'form' %>
  </div>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "newpost.css" %>

<%=link_to "Return to menu", posts_path, class:'menubutton'%>

  <h2 id='header'>Create a new project!</h2>
  <div id = 'form'>
    <%= render'form' %>
  </div>
```

New Post Form

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>

  <div class="section">
  </p> <%=f.text_field :title, id:'titleblock', placeholder:'Title'%><br>
  </div>

  <div class = "section">
    <p class="heading-title"> Description</p> <%= f.text_area :description, class:'postblock', placeholder:'Tell us more about your project...'%>
  </div>

  <div class = "section">
    <p class="heading-title">Looking for...  </p><%= f.text_area :looking_for, class: 'postblock',
                                       placeholder:'What type of financial support are you looking for?'%>
  </div>

  <div class = "section">
    <p class="heading-title">Future plans...</p> <%= f.text_area :future_plans, class:'postblock',
                                         placeholder:'What are some future goals and plans for your project?' %>
  </div>

  <div class = "section">
    Category: <%= f.select :category, options_for_select([['Education'],
                                                          ['Public Sector'],['Hospitality'],['Communication'],
                                                          ['Manufacturing'],['Information Technology'],
                                                          ['Arts & Entertainment'],['Agriculture'],['Technical services']])%><br>
  </div>

  <%= f.file_field :photo, id:'uploadimage'%><br>

  <%= f.submit id:'postbutton'%>


<% end %>
```

Posts model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
  belongs_to :user

  def self.search(search)
    where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?","%#{search.downcase}%","%#{search.downcase}%")
  end

  def filter(filter)
    if filter
      @posts = Post.where(category: filter)
    else
      @posts = Post.all
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: It all looks good. Maybe add some text to your submit tag like `<%= f.submit "submit", id:'postbutton'%> 
`. What would be useful is your server logs. You can see if controller is hit etc..

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is happening"? What are the exact steps that you tried and what did you expect to happen?  Is the page actually being reloaded? If not have you checked if its a rogue event handler?

Comment: Your model has `belongs_to :user`. For some reason, Rails team has decided some time ago to make `belongs_to` to validate the presence of the associated record, meaning that your record is not passing validation.

Comment: @BroiSatse good catch. The default for the `optional:` was changed in Rails 5. I guess if you're not outputting any validation errors or a flash message it would appear that "nothing is happening". This is the kind of regression that tests can catch when it happens.

Comment: @BroiSatse That's exactly what it was. I commented the render for my validation form and it would just get stuck refreshing the page. Thank you!